# Trying to add stickers to existing ipa

Tags: ios, ipa, ios-provisioning

I have an ipa that i build in Defold engine (same situation with Adobe AIR builds). I have no xcode project, only ipa.
I can upoad this build to the app store using Application Loader without any problems.

But I need to add stickers to my application ipa.

What I try to do:

1. Terminal:

   > unzip game.ipa
2. Terminal:

   > codesign -d --entitlements :- Payload/game.app/
3. Save Entitlements.plist with result of p.2
4. I made xcode project with stickers  (I experements with 2 project one as stickers pack, and other as game app + stickers target)

*Stickers app should use the same certificate, 
Id of stickers app should be the same like id of the main app + one word with dot, for example:
main app is com.mygame
stickers is com.mygame.stickers (it should be only one dot after main id)*

5. I made an archive of sticker project
6. Export archive for the appstore
7. Then I extracted PlugIns folder with stickers (in this folder I have my stickers.appex) from the ipa (p6)
8. I made a copy PlugIns forlder to my game.app (p2)
9. Terminal:

   > codesign -f -s "my cert" --entitlements Entitlements.plist Payload/game.app/
10. Terminal:

    > zip -qr "game_with_stickers.ipa” Payload

Then, if I try to upload my result ipa to the App Store using Application loader.
Loader doesn’t show me any errors, but then, after post-processing on store I receive a message:

> Invalid iMessage App - Your iMessage app contains an invalid sticker
>   pack. The app may have been built or signed with non-compliant or
>   prerelease tools. For more information, go to developer.apple.com.

Original ipa with stickers (ater xcode p.6) has MessagesApplicationExtensionSupport folder near  "Payload" folder, when I try to add this folder to my ipa, I receive email from Apple:

> Invalid Messages Application Support - The files
>   MessagesApplicationExtensionStub don’t match
>   YourGame.app/PlugIns/Stickers.appex/MessagesApplicationExtensionStub.
>   Make sure the files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it.
>   Don’t apply post-processing to
>   YourGame.app/PlugIns/Stickers.appex/MessagesApplicationExtensionStub.

When I made all this steps with dev-provisioning - it's works on my device without any problems.

Hope somebody can help me to find right way to upload build to the App Strore

**UPD, ANSWER:**
I change next parameters in plist to parameters like in stickers app:

```
 <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
        <string>16F73</string>

<key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
        <string>14E8301</string>

 <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
        <string>10.3</string>

 <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
        <string>14E8301</string>

 <key>DTSDKName</key>
        <string>iphoneos10.3</string>

 <key>DTXcode</key>
        <string>0833</string>

 <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
        <string>8E3004b</string>
```

Minimum ios version should be :

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>10.0</string>
```

And I added next key to solve issue with UI components for ipad pro with multitasking:

```
 <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
```

I am not sure that I have to change all this parameters (maybe I need to change just one or two.
I hope my hack by hands of this parameters did not affect on the build.